# Are browsers other than Firefox planning on supporting -moz CSS properties, or does CSS3 have an equivalent?

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser, browser-support

As of right now I believe only Firefox support `-moz-border-radius` property. I am surprised that twitter uses it.

Are any other browsers planning on supporting this or does CSS3 have something like this in the works?

**Edit:** I also found [-webkit-border-top-left-radius](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/) and then the [CSS3 version](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-border-20021107/#border-radius)

So when is CSS3 coming out?

Answer (score 10):

[CSS3 has `border-radius`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius).

For now, Mozilla- and WebKit-based browsers have experimental support, `-moz-border-radius` and `-webkit-border-radius`. It's not bad to use them now, as long as you understand they are temporary measures until they are properly implemented. I would expect it's not too long before you see full support for `border-radius` in Mozilla, Firefox and IE. (Well, hopefully IE.)

**Update:** as of August 2016, with [border-radius being natively available](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius) in all native desktop browsers (and most mobile browsers, not to mention), the stringency of using `-moz-border-radius`, `-webkit-border-radius` and similar is being slowly relaxed.

Answer (score 3):

Because the CSS3 spec hasn't been finalised, Mozilla and Webkit decided to implement their own method of rounded corners, doing it in the correct way, by adding the vendor-specific tag at the front.

This is done so that when the CSS3 is FINALLY released, should they change how border-radius is supposed to work (eg: the order of the parameters), then none of the sites using the vendor-specific methods will be broken. Mozilla and WebKit can just go ahead and implement the W3C style and developers can slowly move over to that.

It's not too surprising that you're seeing some websites using it, especially for something like rounded corners where it's not going to make a massive difference to the user experience. And I mean, it's just IE users who are missing out, and they deserve everything they get.

Answer (score 3):

It bugs me when people talk about CSS3 coming out. It's not a complete spec like the previous ones. It has been broken up into separate modules that may increment their versions independently.

So *Selectors Level 4* may make Recommendation before *CSS Backgrounds and Borders Level 3* does.

So, will CSS3 arrive? Eventually, but not all a once. So don't wait for it, start using it now (where applicable).

Answer (score 2):

CSS3 has something like this in the works.

Comment: Will -moz-border-radius going to fade away? Should you not use it?

Comment: @twodayslate, use both the CSS3 property (for the future) and the Mozilla extension, if you really want the feature.  If usage of it fades away, take it out.  No harm keeping it now, though.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024.aspx#border), IE 8 will ***not*** support border-radius.

Answer (score 1):

Any CSS property that starts with a dash (e.g. `-moz`, `-webkit`) is a browser-specific property.

This allows browser vendors to experiment with new CSS properties. Doing so is a common part of the process for writing new CSS specs, to allow web developers to see how the properties work and raise issues.

Hence you’ll find a lot of CSS 3 properties, like `border-radius` currently implemented in some browsers with vendor-specific extensions.

There’s nothing particularly wrong with using these on production sites, as long as you’re aware they’ll only work in the one browser.

CSS 3 should be out any decade now :)

Answer (score 1):

Browser-based properties are only meant for interim fixes for that particular browser, and are supposed to be deprecated when either the W3C adopts them into CSS, or not. I wouldn't rely on them to be cross-browser or even be kept for the particular browser.